# How to resolve angular $digest error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have implemented `emailPattern` method to validate specific email address , so when my modal window pops up i see below error , how to resolve `$digest` error in angularjs ?

main.html

```
<md-input-container flex="100">
            <label>Cc</label>
            <md-chips ng-model="notifyCtrl.cc" name="email"
                      md-separator-keys="customKeys"
                      md-transform-chip="addChips($chip)"
                      md-add-on-blur='true'
                      ng-pattern="emailPattern($chip)"
                      name="email">
            </md-chips>
            <div class="help-block" ng-messages="notifyForm.email.$error" ng-show="notifyForm.email.$touched && notifyForm.email.$invalid">
                <div ng-message="pattern">An email must contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _ characters.</div>
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
```

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.emailPattern = function(elementValue){
         var emailPattern = /^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{3}[a-z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
         console.log(emailPattern.test(elementValue));
         return emailPattern;
       }
```

Error

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"emailPattern($chip)","newVal":{},"oldVal":{}}],[{"msg":"emailPattern($chip)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"emailPattern($chip)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"emailPattern($chip)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}],[{"msg":"emailPattern($chip)","newVal":{},"oldVal":"..."}]]
```

Comment: Parse a regex directly into `ng-pattern` instead a function and you will be fine.

Comment: ok, i tried that but in case of invalid email address its not displaying `ng-message`

Comment: Short answer is - never use functions in html except as event (ng-click etc.) handlers. Long answer is long)

Comment: i have to try different approach if i do not see expected result.